# How to fix problems with background img and wrap text around img in BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 issues with my bootstrap code:
- I can't put a background (ok wtf the background image work on this site, but not at home !?)
- I can't wrap my text around an image

I tried this solution but it doesn't work for me
[Wrap text around bootstrap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165940/wrap-text-around-bootstrap-image)

```css
.site-heading .site-heading-upper {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.page-section {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url('https://wallpapersite.com/images/wallpapers/yosemite-valley-1680x1050-yosemite-national-park-california-5223.jp');
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <title>Chrysallid</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="intro" class="view">
    <div class="full-bg-img"></div>
   </div>

    <div class="container d-none d-md-block" align="center">
      <img src="img/logoC.png" width="25%">
     </div>

   

     <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
      <img class="img-fluid mb-3 mt-3 rounded" src="http://images.8tracks.com/cover/i/009/320/238/hands-keys-music-piano-play-Favim-8937.png" alt="" width="100%">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
      <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>titre</h2>
       </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-justify">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

i think to use text-white to change color of text

```css
.site-heading .site-heading-upper {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.page-section {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url('https://wallpapersite.com/images/wallpapers/yosemite-valley-1680x1050-yosemite-national-park-california-5223.jp');
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <title>Chrysallid</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="intro" class="view">
    <div class="full-bg-img"></div>
   </div>

    <div class="container d-none d-md-block" align="center">
      <img src="img/logoC.png" width="25%">
     </div>

   

     <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
      <img class="img-fluid mb-3 mt-3 rounded" src="http://images.8tracks.com/cover/i/009/320/238/hands-keys-music-piano-play-Favim-8937.png" alt="" width="100%">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
      <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>titre</h2>
       </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-justify text-white">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```