# Bootstrap - Wrap text around image not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to wrap text around an image, just like this issue:

[Wrap text around bootstrap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165940/wrap-text-around-bootstrap-image/49273631)

I have tried all the solutions there and none of them worked.

Here is my layout I am working with:

```
div.col-md-6
    img.imagePost(src=`/{{{blogPost['feature-image-2']}}}`)
    | {{#if blogPost['feature-image-3'] == ""}}
    video.postVideo(controls)
        source(src=`/{{{blogPost['video']}}}`) 
    | {{else}}
    img.imagePost(src=`/{{{blogPost['feature-image-3']}}}`)
    | {{/if}}
    | {{#if blogPost['feature-image-4'] != ""}}
    img.imagePost(src=`/{{{blogPost['feature-image-4']}}}`)
    | {{/if}}
div(style=`float: none;`)
    | {{{blogPost['post']}}}
```

Comment: Please post actual rendered HTML (or a representative sample) rather than templating.

Comment: But basically you'd wrap your images in a container having class `float-left` or `float-start` (please tag your Bootstrap version). That alone should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding pull-left along with imagePost in your jade/pug file if you are using bootstrap 3.3. You can also remove the last wrapper div with float none. Final code will looks like this.

```
div.col-md-6
  img.imagePost.pull-left(src=`/{{{blogPost['feature-image-2']}}}`)
  | {{#if blogPost['feature-image-3'] == ""}}
  video.postVideo(controls)
    source(src=`/{{{blogPost['video']}}}`) 
  | {{else}}
  img.imagePost.pull-left(src=`/{{{blogPost['feature-image-3']}}}`)
  | {{/if}}
  | {{#if blogPost['feature-image-4'] != ""}}
  img.imagePost.pull-left(src=`/{{{blogPost['feature-image-4']}}}`)
  | {{/if}}
  | {{{blogPost['post']}}}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, the first paragraph of text wraps but after that all other paragraphs go below the images

Comment: Can you please elaborate whether the blogPost['post'] is returning string or string contains html tag in it

Comment: string contains html tag in it, so it has about 10 paragraph tags

Comment: Check to see if this solve your problem. Created a dummy variable to make the string as html https://codepen.io/prathap937/pen/rNGbzbd

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be useful if you create separate CSS class

See this example :

Css:

```
.wrapper {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6; 
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.star {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  shape-outside: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg);
  shape-margin:20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.moon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px; 
  width:200px;
  background-color: #2badd9;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: inset(1% round 50%);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg" alt="" class="star">
  
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use. </p>
  
  
  <div class="moon"></div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use. </p>
</div>
```

Result will be like this :

[image: wrap text around an image]

It is hard to guess the cause of your problem because you haven't shared the entire HTML so hope this example helps!